# stop spammer attack over postfix/dovecot

Tags: postfix, malware

I've got a server with postfix/dovecot which is somehow being attacked. I constantly see huge amount of logs like this (replaced my domain by example.com):

```
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/pickup[14702]: 878D313894B: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/cleanup[14916]: 878D313894B: message-id=<20180702080303.878D313894B@example.com>
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/qmgr[19570]: 878D313894B: from=<www-data@example.com>, size=40324, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  2 10:03:05 my-server postfix/smtp[14923]: 878D313894B: to=<mdm12xx@hotmail.com>, relay=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.42.33]:25, delay=2.1, delays=0.03/0.03/1.1/0.93, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20180702080303.878D313894B@example.com> [InternalId=11360188501262, Hostname=BY2NAM03HT083.eop-NAM03.prod.protection.outlook.com] 45866 bytes in 0.498, 89.854 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Jul  2 10:03:05 my-server postfix/qmgr[19570]: 878D313894B: removed


Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/pickup[14702]: 97D4E138950: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/cleanup[14916]: 97D4E138950: message-id=<20180702080303.97D4E138950@example.com>
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/qmgr[19570]: 97D4E138950: from=<www-data@example.com>, size=40308, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/smtp[14933]: 97D4E138950: to=<a@a>, relay=none, delay=0.14, delays=0.01/0.02/0.11/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=a type=AAAA: Host not found)
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/bounce[14935]: 97D4E138950: sender non-delivery notification: B9416138951
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/qmgr[19570]: 97D4E138950: removed


Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/cleanup[14916]: A6851138951: message-id=<20180702080303.A6851138951@example.com>
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/qmgr[19570]: A6851138951: from=<>, size=42121, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/bounce[14935]: 9C33113894C: sender non-delivery notification: A6851138951
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server dovecot: lmtp(service@example.com): mNzcKTfcOVtZOgAAruHjSQ: msgid=<20180702080303.A6851138951@example.com>: saved mail to INBOX
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/lmtp[14936]: A6851138951: to=<service@example.com>, orig_to=<www-data@example.com>, relay=example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.03, delays=0/0.01/0.01/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <service@example.com> mNzcKTfcOVtZOgAAruHjSQ Saved)
Jul  2 10:03:03 my-server postfix/qmgr[19570]: A6851138951: removed
```

I've already tried to configure postfix with following rules in order to avoid this kind of attacks, it has calmed down the magnitude but the server is still receiving huge amount of activity:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**:

```
#################################################################
# ANTI SPAM: https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual_postfix_antispam
#################################################################
smtpd_helo_required     = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
unknown_address_reject_code  = 554
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 554
unknown_client_reject_code   = 554

smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_address

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    regexp:/etc/postfix/antispam/helo.regexp,
    permit
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
#        permit_sasl_authenticated,
#        permit_mynetworks,
#        reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
   check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/antispam/helo_client_exceptions
#   check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/antispam/sender_checks,
   reject_invalid_hostname,
### Can cause issues with Auth SMTP, so be weary!
   reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
##################################
   reject_non_fqdn_sender,
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   reject_unknown_sender_domain,
   reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
   permit_mynetworks,
   reject_unauth_destination,
# Add RBL exceptions here, when changing rbl_client_exceptions, this file must be regenerated using postmap <file>, to generate a Berkeley DB
          check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/antispam/rbl_client_exceptions,
          reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
#          reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
          reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, 
#          reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org 
          reject_rhsbl_sender dsn.rfc-ignorant.org,
#         check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:60000,
         permit 

smtpd_relay_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
#   permit_sasl_authenticated,
    defer_unauth_destination
```

I'm afraid that this server is being used to somehow send spam to people, so it can annoy people and damage my IP reputation.

I've dedicated lots of hours investigating and reading documentation on internet, but I'm still confused about what is going on and how to stop it. I would like to know how the attacker is using this server and how can I stop the attacks.

Don't know if it's related, today I've received an email from my hosting provider saying that they suspended the server because they detected unusual activity (twice today, twice 15 days ago):

```
Attack detail : 173Kpps/38Mbps
dateTime                   srcIp:srcPort           dstIp:dstPort           protocol flags       bytes reason               
2018.07.02 16:35:04 CEST   xx.xx.xx.xx:41403      78.46.61.106:80         UDP      ---            29 ATTACK:UDP
```

I've closed all ports except TCP 22, 80, 443, 25, 587, 993, 995, 465, so I hope that outgoing UDP is now blocked. I'm not sure if there is some malware installed inside the server triggering this activity and how to detect it.

Comment: the `www-data` user may indicate a web service that is running bad code (script that allows open mail relay via form submission) or has been compromised. maybe look at that?

Comment: If you manage to inspect in the  postfix queue some of those messages, it will probably even tell you the name of the PHP script involved on this.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro how can I inspect the queue? If I exec `sudo -u www-data mailq` it says empty queue...

Comment: When you got there messages, obviously. You might close port 25 to the outside world for a while if you want to get them faster. Or run a `ngrep` over port 25, but beware of confidentiality issues of seeing emails you should not be seeing.

Comment: I'd suggest you block OUTBOUND traffic on port 25 for now. `iptables -I OUTPUT --protocol TCP --dport 25 -j REJECT`

Comment: @roaima but I need to send emails from this server... What I've done for now is to eliminate `www-data` alias in mysql tables, so it will not be a valid user and hope that rules from postfix will block all emails from www-data...

Comment: You should locate that web script nonetheless. They can use it to issue commands in your web servers, and eventually it will allow an attacker to escalate to root. Masking the problem wont do any good in the medium term.

Comment: You need to block outbound emails until you've identified the flaw. Then you can review the message queue and delete those that are spam.

Comment: I suspect the problem can be because an old version of drupal 7.54, I'll try to update it... I've tried also to log the script that sends emails via `mail.log` without success, I suppose that it uses another mail sender (phpmailer)